# Table 'mysql.transaction_registry' doesn't exist in engine (1932)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to backup a database using `mysqldump` but I got this error:

```sql
Trying to backup MySQL database... mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `transaction_registry`':
Table 'mysql.transaction_registry' doesn't exist in engine (1932)
```

the problem first were with `innodb_index_stats` & `innodb_table_stats` and followed the instructions and worked well but got another problem

I tried from these [1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/cannot-open-table-mysql-innodb-index-stats/48189#48189) - [2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54608/innodb-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found-after-upgrade-to-mys/54624#54624),  but still getting the same error, any ideas?

Comment: What is the version you are using?

Comment: mysql 10.5.12-1.el7.centos

Comment: Run `mariadb-upgrade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I ended doing is like that:

Removed corrupted tables:
`rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/mysql/transaction_registry.idb`

Recreated the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE transaction_registry (
transaction_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
commit_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
begin_timestamp timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000', 
commit_timestamp timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000', 
isolation_level enum('READ-UNCOMMITTED','READ-COMMITTED','REPEATABLE-READ','SERIALIZABLE') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id), 
UNIQUE KEY commit_id (commit_id), KEY begin_timestamp (begin_timestamp), KEY commit_timestamp (commit_timestamp,transaction_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin STATS_PERSISTENT=0 ;
```

*Ref: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqltransaction_registry-table/*