# MariaDB Backup is not possible anymore because InnoDB is broken, why so?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos, mariadb-10.3

Version: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.34-MariaDB

After trying to do a backup on my mariadb server i got:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `transaction_registry`': Table 'mysql.transaction_registry' doesn't exist in engine (1932)
```

Which I know is a common mistake. I then researched and decided to drop the table and create it again. (Source: [Table 'mysql.transaction_registry' doesn't exist in engine (1932)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477956/table-mysql-transaction-registry-doesnt-exist-in-engine-1932))

Mariadb could not be restarted afterwards(This is my problem I am trying to fix)

Here is what I already tried:

1. Created a new mysql appliance and copied the transaction_registry to my actual database. No good.
2. Remove ib_logfile*

Additional Information:
/var/log/mysql/mariadb.err:

```
   2022-10-28 10:06:45 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-10-28 10:06:45 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-10-28 10:06:45 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-10-28 10:06:45 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-10-28 10:06:45 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2022-10-28 10:13:17 0 [Note] Initializing built-in plugins
2022-10-28 10:13:17 0 [Note] Initializing plugins specified on the command line
2022-10-28 10:13:17 0 [Note] Initializing installed plugins
2022-10-28 10:13:17 0 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': unsigned value 4 adjusted to 2097152
2022-10-28 10:13:17 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: innodb_page_size=16384 requires innodb_buffer_pool_size >= 5MiB current 2MiB
2022-10-28 10:13:17 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-10-28 10:13:17 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-10-28 10:13:17 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-10-28 10:13:17 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-10-28 10:13:17 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2022-10-28 10:13:44 0 [Note] Initializing built-in plugins
2022-10-28 10:13:44 0 [Note] Initializing plugins specified on the command line
2022-10-28 10:13:44 0 [Note] Initializing installed plugins
2022-10-28 10:13:44 0 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': unsigned value 4 adjusted to 2097152
2022-10-28 10:13:44 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: innodb_page_size=16384 requires innodb_buffer_pool_size >= 5MiB current 2MiB
2022-10-28 10:13:44 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-10-28 10:13:44 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-10-28 10:13:44 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-10-28 10:13:44 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-10-28 10:13:44 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2022-10-28 10:16:00 0 [Note] Initializing built-in plugins
2022-10-28 10:16:00 0 [Note] Initializing plugins specified on the command line
2022-10-28 10:16:00 0 [Note] Initializing installed plugins
2022-10-28 10:16:00 0 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': unsigned value 5 adjusted to 2097152
2022-10-28 10:16:00 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: innodb_page_size=16384 requires innodb_buffer_pool_size >= 5MiB current 2MiB
2022-10-28 10:16:00 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-10-28 10:16:00 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-10-28 10:16:00 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-10-28 10:16:00 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-10-28 10:16:00 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2022-10-28 11:24:32 0 [Note] Initializing built-in plugins
2022-10-28 11:24:32 0 [Note] Initializing plugins specified on the command line
2022-10-28 11:24:32 0 [Note] Initializing installed plugins
2022-10-28 11:24:32 0 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': unsigned value 5 adjusted to 2097152
2022-10-28 11:24:32 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: innodb_page_size=16384 requires innodb_buffer_pool_size >= 5MiB current 2MiB
2022-10-28 11:24:32 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-10-28 11:24:32 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-10-28 11:24:32 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-10-28 11:24:32 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-10-28 11:24:32 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2022-10-28 11:43:17 0 [Note] Initializing built-in plugins
2022-10-28 11:43:17 0 [Note] Initializing plugins specified on the command line
2022-10-28 11:43:17 0 [Note] Initializing installed plugins
2022-10-28 11:43:17 0 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': unsigned value 5 adjusted to 2097152
2022-10-28 11:43:17 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: innodb_page_size=16384 requires innodb_buffer_pool_size >= 5MiB current 2MiB
2022-10-28 11:43:17 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-10-28 11:43:17 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-10-28 11:43:17 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-10-28 11:43:17 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-10-28 11:43:17 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

my.cnf:

```
[client-server]
[mysqld]
pid-file = "/var/run/mysqld/mysql.pid"
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_log_file_size=1G
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Please let me know if you need any additional Information.

Answer (score 1):

Good news, its not broken, not all innodb errors are broken stuff. Sometime they mean what they say "[ERROR] InnoDB: innodb_page_size=16384 requires innodb_buffer_pool_size >= 5MiB current 2MiB".

Your configuration file isn't being read by the server. Somewhere is a configuration file or command line that has `innodb_buffer_pool_size=4` (or 5 in later restarts). Because this value it too small, it uses 2MiB which is only the minimum if the page size is 4k.

"Remove ib_logfile*" this is a sure way to break to your current MariaDB. Don't do it.

So look exactly how mariadb is started:

```
 sudo -u mysql mysqld --help --verbose | head -n 10
```

Will contain an output:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Check your file is there. Check the permissions on your `my.cnf` file.

Comment: I already removed the ib_logfile files.. I gave up and restored the machine to its previous state. So back to problem 1: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `transaction_registry`': Table 'mysql.transaction_registry' doesn't exist in engine (1932)


This is the problem that made me start the work on my mysql tables, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: `drop table mysql.transaction_registry`, `mysql_upgrade --force`